# How can I permit an AppImage to access screen sharing feature?

Tags: permissions, appimage

I've been using Gap messenger for a while and when I want to use the screen sharing option, the app says "not permitted!" and I don't know how to permit an AppImage to use this option.
here is the AppImage:
https://desktop.gap.im/linux/

I use Ubuntu Desktop 20.04

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: I added my Linux version